# Differentiate:$ x^{2y} = \ln y$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am having trouble with the following equation defined implicitly with respect to $x$.I figured I could use the quotient rule or maybe play around with the logs, however I always need to differentiate $x^{2y}$ which I have no idea how to do, any help will be appreciated.

Differentiate $x^{2y} = \ln y$, with respect to $x$.

Comment: You wrote $x^2y$. Perhaps you meant $x^{2y}$?

Comment: yes I did, sorry

Comment: You meant $x^{2y}$?

Comment: "Play around with logs" is a good idea, keep going with that.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Why did you delete your post? I tried to upvote it yet I couldn't because it was deleted,  so I posted my answer.

Comment: @Timbuc He/She wants $x^{2y}$ not $x^2y$ sa we thought.

Comment: "Differentiate" what with respect to what?

Comment: @Did, it doesn't matter, differentiate means to form differentials.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Sorry but do you know what you are talking about?

Comment: @Did Well we can only ever be so sure... but I was under the impression that if http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal) are in your equation, then it has been differentiated; it is a differential equation whether it be in the form of dy/dx or dx/dy. It doesn't matter which variable the derivative is with respect to unless a particular variable was specifically asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $y(x)= f(x)$. 
$$\begin{align}e^{\ln (x^{2y})} = \ln y &\Rightarrow e^{2y \ln x} = \ln y \Rightarrow e^{2y \ln x}\Big(\frac{2y}{x} + 2y'\ln x\Big) = \frac{y'}{y} \\&\Rightarrow y' - 2yy'\ e^{2y \ln x} \ln x= \frac{2y^2}{x}e^{2y \ln x} \Rightarrow y' = \frac{2y^2\ \ e^{2y \ln x}}{x(1 - 2y\ e^{2y \ln x} \ln x)}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $x^{2y}=\ln(y)$ rewriting this as $e^{2y\ln(x)}=\ln(y)$ now differentiaitng with respect to $x$: $e^{2y\ln(x)}(2y'\ln(x)+\frac{2y}{x})=\frac{1}{y}{y'}$

Answer (score 0):

Inplicit differentiation:

$$x^{2y}=\log y\implies 2yx^{2y-1}\,dx+2x^{2y}\log x\,dy=\frac1ydy\implies\left(\frac1y-2x^{2y}\log x\right)dy=2yx^{2y-1}\,dx\implies$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2yx^{2y-1}}{\frac1y-2x^{2y}\log x}=\frac{2x^{2y-1}y^2}{1-2x^{2y}y\log x}$$

The answer was edited since the OP was.

Comment: It is not a mistake, @AaronMaroja: the original post was $\;x^2y\;$ , and then it was edited!